# Show that the natural map $\mathbb{C}/\Gamma \to \mathbb{C}/\Gamma'$ is holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

> Let $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ be two lattices in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\Gamma \subseteq \Gamma'$. Show that the natural map $\mathbb{C}/\Gamma \to \mathbb{C}/\Gamma'$ is holomorphic.

The map $f: \mathbb{C}/\Gamma \to \mathbb{C}/\Gamma'$ is holomorphic if and only if $f \circ \pi_1 : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}/\Gamma'$ is holomorphic where $\pi_1: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}/L$.

Now we know that the projections are holomorphic so what I want to deduce is that $ f\circ \pi_1 = \pi_2$ where $\pi_2$ is the projection $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}/\Gamma'$. Is this true?

Comment: No, I don't think that $f \circ \pi_1 = \pi_2$ is necessarily true unless $\Gamma = \Gamma'$. What is true though is that you can find a lifting $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ of $f \circ \pi_1$ with respect to $\pi_2$ that is holomorphic. As holomorphicity is a local property, so you can write $f$ locally as a composition of holomorphic maps and is therefore holomorphic.